# beautiful soup scrape multi page missing value on next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Im using Beautifulsoup to scrape list of car name and price on multi page site. In one page it contains 40 data and the code is working correctly if only to scrape one page. When it comes to scrape multi page (this case i only scrape two page to check if the code is working properly), i found that there's always missing data at the beginning of next page (column 'price'), which makes the data is not properly align starting at data 41 onward.

some note on the data for price column: the price listed could be as it is ('ads_price_highlight') or it could be ('ads_price'), as a discounted price.

below are the code i create to parse multi page for this case. I still have no idea why i got this missing data on price column while the other column is correct.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np

from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

car = []
price = []

pages = np.arange(1,3,1)

for page in pages:

  url = 'https://www.mudah.my/malaysia/cars-for-sale/perodua?o='+ str(page) +'&q=&so=1&th=1'
  page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
  car_list = soup.find_all('li', class_='listing_ads_params')

  sleep(randint(2,10))

  for container in car_list:
        cars = container.find('div', {'class':'top_params_col1'})
        if cars is not None:
            car.append(cars.find('h2', {'class': 'list_title'}).text)   

        prices2 = container.find('div', class_='ads_price_highlight')
        if prices2 is not None:
            price.append(prices2.text)

        prices = container.find('div', class_='ads_price')
        if prices is not None:
            price.append(prices.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = list(zip(car, price)),
                    columns = ['car', 'price'])

df.to_csv(r'carprice.csv', index = False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going:

1.) The standard `html.parser` doesn't parse this page well, use `lxml` or `html5lib`

2.) The page has *"dummy"* ad listing between regular ads with `class="honey-pot"`, so the script needs to take care of them.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.mudah.my/malaysia/cars-for-sale/perodua?o={page}&q=&so=1&th=1'
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

for page in range(1, 3):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers).content, 'lxml')

    for title, price in zip(soup.select('#list-view-ads .list_ads:not(.honey-pot) .list_title'),
                            soup.select('#list-view-ads .list_ads:not(.honey-pot) div[class^="ads_price"]')):
        print('{:<60}{}'.format(title.get_text(strip=True), price.get_text(strip=True)))
```

Prints:

```
Ladies Owner/SE B.Kit-2008 Perodua MYVI 1.3 EZ (A)          RM 15 800
Perodua MYVI 1.3 EZ (A) LIMETED EDITION                     RM 16 800
Perodua MYVI 1.3 SX FACELIFT (M)                            RM 10 990
Perodua VIVA 1.0 (A) ONE OWNER ACC FREE                     RM 9 800
Perodua KELISA 1.0 SE EZS (A) Jaga Baik                     RM 13 990
Perodua MYVI 1.3 EZi (A) PASSO RACY~17" RIMS                RM 22 990
Perodua MYVI 1.3 (A) EZi tru 2007                           RM 14 800
23k KM SUPER CARKING 2010 Perodua MYVI 1.3 EZ (A)           RM 16 800
Perodua MYVI 1.3(M) SX 1 owner Ori mielage                  RM 10 800
Perodua MYVI H/AV 1.5L (A) R3Bat3 2XXX                      RM 50 600
Perodua ARUZ X 1.5L (A) R3BaT3 2XXX                         RM 72 600
Perodua AXIA GXTRA R3BAT3 1XXX                              RM 35 300

...and so on.
```